Green line on screen of certain Android smartphones
Recently, a green line mysteriously appeared on the screen of my Android smartphone. This happened a few days after I installed an Android 14.0 update. I believe the update caused the green line issue. Later, I learned that many Android smartphone users are facing this issue. As an Android enthusiast, I am curious to see why this happened. I learned that the issue, a hardware defect, affects phones with AMOLED displays and causes a permanent green line to appear on the screen. I read a blog that states

The green line issue is a hardware problem when the display connector or flex cable connecting the display to the motherboard gets loose, damaged, or defective. This causes permanent and irreversible damage to the display, resulting in a thin band of green that runs from the top to the bottom of the screen.

I am posting this question for answers that would help me understand the technical details behind this issue. How does this issue occur technically? Any insights are highly appreciated. Thank you!
Edit:
My Android phone model is OnePlus 9R.

If it is caused by software then it is most likely a driver problem. Anyway you should edit your question and include your Android phone model name, so other users having the same phone model and facing the same problems will know that this is not a hardware problem.
